# Is this possible to reuse the .so file when changing the .h file

Tags: c++, c

I currently try to use the API from the `.so` file which was given by customer. Then I fixed some `#define` value in `.h` file to see the different results. In this case, if the `.so` file related to the `.h` file, is this possible to reuse the `.so` file when modifying the `.h` file?

Comment: Maybe yes. Maybe no. Depends on how the #defines are used. Likely answer: "No".

Comment: Can you clarify '.so file related to the .h' ? If the '.so' DEPENDS on the '.h' file (e.g., used it for the built), than the answer from @John3136 holds.

Comment: Please show us which `#define`s you have changed in which way. Then we *might* have an idea about the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "probably not".

It depends how the #defines are used in the library (which you may not know if you don't have the source).

- If the #defines are just some constants for the user but not used by the library then you'll be ok.
- If the defines are things like buffer sizes and you make them smaller, you should be ok (you just wont use the whole buffer)
- If the defines are buffer sizes and you make them bigger you'll have problems - your code expects bigger buffers than the library has
- If the defines are chars to look for it won't work - the library will be sending/receiving different characters than your code expects.

As you can see: no hard and fast rule, but the safe answer is you'll have to recompile the library with the new .h files.

Comment: Your second point is only valid if the memory management is done entirely within the library. But if the client code has to allocate buffers of specific sizes, then the library will access fields after the allocated space. Can be "fun" to debug.